# Retrieving params from a POST request React.js --> Node.js using Axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have a client side (React.js) and a server side (Node.js) of my project. I am using axios to submit POST requests to my server, and it looks like this on the front end:

```
const signUp = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/signup', {
      username: name,
      password: password
    }).then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

This is happening once I click a certain button.

In my Node.js file, I am trying to access this username and password field, like this:

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.username)
});
```

however I cannot figure out how to do it. I'm using express and cors as well. I've been researching it for about 2 hours now and can't find an answer even though it seems so simple, or maybe I'm just missing something! I keep getting undefined whenever trying to access req.body.

Comment: Have you enabled JSON on the server?

Comment: did you used `app.use(express.json());` or bodyParser before `app.post()`?

Comment: Hey @jonrsharpe, sorry for being an idiot but how exactly do I do that?

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json, as mentioned in the other comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, yes... the answer is simple.

I forgot to do app.use(express.json()) before making the post request. This can be done by the following lines of code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
```

and then making the post request. Cheers!